# Increase polygon count for sphere in Visual Studio model editor

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm creating a simple sphere in the Visual Studio 2015 model editor, and it's fine, but the polgygon count is low (400) for a smooth sphere.  You can see the silhouette of the facets far too much.

There's a "subdivide" button in the editor but its always disabled.  There's a smoothing angle option but changing it doesn't seem to do anything for the edges.

How can I increase the polgygon count for smoother edges on the silhouette?

Comment: Wouldn't the shading take care of that?

Comment: Not unless you tell me how.  I don't mean the shading of the face, remember, it's the silhouette of the sphere that's the problem.

Comment: I can't find any references offhand that would demonstrate it, but you could have a fragment shader that makes the texture transparent when the normals are close to 90 degrees away from the view ray, and the fragment is past the sphere's radius. That's all with the assumption that you need to keep the poly counts low. I know nothing about VS's editor :(